# TensorFlow library was compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine. Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow following the  https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip
 steps. I installed it through Anaconda.

I also tried using a virtual environment without using anaconda as this page provided (please check image). It also gave the same error.

[image]

Following images shows the versions I have installed and its given error.

I am using,

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- x86_64
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Duo CPU T5870 @ 2.00 GHz 2.00 GHz
- Installed memory (RAM): 2.00 GB

[image]

Version:
[image]

Error:
[image]

I tried to overcome this but, I couldn't find a solution. I am new to tensorflow and trying to install and learn it. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Try to create a new conda env, and install TF via conda.

Comment: I tried it. but not worked. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I faced same problem, when I tried to run TensorFlow in a kvm virtual Ubuntu 18.04 server. My machine runs tf fine as non virtual, Processor is old, but AMD64.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your CPU is too old for running TensorFlow as it lacks the required Instruction set. `Starting with TensorFlow 1.6, binaries use AVX instructions which may not run on older CPUs.` - According to Tensorflow.

You have 2 possible solutions:

1. Using cloud/web based solution, e.g. Google Colab
2. Upgrade your Machine to a modern build

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am trying this from three days and I did the dual boot with Windows 7 to use Ubuntu. Are you sure my CPU is not enough to run TensorFlow? What is the way to confirm it?

Comment: I edited my question and added more information about my computer using 'lscpu'. Please check them.

Comment: I am fairly certain about your CPU lacking SSE4.1, not to mention AVX instruction set. According to Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#SSE4.1 They introduce the SSE4.1 after you the gen your CPU is in, moreover in order to run AVX, I do believe you need Inter Core processors(i.e. celeron, pentium, i3, i5, i7 etc.)

Comment: I think you are right. I tried by installing TensorFlow 1.5. It works. But, 1.6., 1.7.,1.12 not. Thank you very much for your reply.                                                                                                                                              I have no better idea about Google Colab. I planning to do deep learning research. So, I think it is not a good solution.

Comment: @Dreamer: Intel celeron/pentium CPUs *don't* have AVX, unlike i3 and higher.  (That changed with Ice Lake; now even the lowest-end Intel CPUs have AVX2.)  All AMD Zen CPUs have AVX2, they don't sell crippled versions.

Comment: Are you sure you can't build from source without SSE4.2 or SSE4.1?  It would make sense that this is just talking about the pre-built binaries, not that they removed portable fallback code.

Answer (score 17):

Thanks for the earlier answers.
I was facing the exact problem for SSE4.2 instruction.
I installed tensorflow 1.5 instead of 1.12 and it is working.

### Error message on my system

```
The TensorFlow library was compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

### Solution

Here is what I did:

Please run these inside virtual environment:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow

pip install tensorflow==1.5
```

You can replace 1.5 with any version that suits your machine.

Try importing it again it should run now

Comment: Yes, this is a temporary solution to run tensorflow on our machine. But, for the implementation of the latest things using tensorflow 1.5 is not enough.

Comment: This helped me in my kvm-virtualised server.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error on the laptop HP ProBook 4720s:

```
python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2019-04-16 17:50:25.829023: F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:37] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use AVX instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

But I installed TensorFlow via Anaconda `conda` installation:

```
conda install tensorflow  # install TensorFlow for CPU
conda activate DL3  # activate virtual environment DL3

python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.__version__)
1.13.1
>>> exit()
```