# Is it possible to run python with the tensorflow library on an vps based on kvm

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running a KVM VPS (virtual private server) with Debian 10 installed.
Since the server should do some python3 machine learning work, I installed

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

Which installs fine, but `import tensorflow` in a file (Python 3.9.2 installed) ends in the error:

```
The TensorFlow library was compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
```

Some information about the CPU:

```
lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          1
On-line CPU(s) list:             0
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              1
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      15
Model:                           6
Model name:                      Common KVM processor
Stepping:                        1
CPU MHz:                         2599.998
BogoMIPS:                        5199.99
Hypervisor vendor:               KVM
Virtualization type:             full
L1d cache:                       32 KiB
L1i cache:                       32 KiB
L2 cache:                        4 MiB
L3 cache:                        16 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion
Vulnerability Mds:               Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT Host stat
                                 e unknown
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Vulnerable
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Retpolines, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat ps
                                 e36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm constant_tsc nopl xtopol
                                 ogy cpuid tsc_known_freq pni cx16 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm cpuid_fa
                                 ult pti
```

Installing and old version tensorflow library does not work

> pip3 install tensorflow==1.5
> ERROR: Could not find a version
> that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.5 (from versions: 2.5.0,
> 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.5

Does anyone have an idea how to use tensorflow inside KVM maschine?

Comment: There is no error message in your question

Comment: Thanks a lot. Somehow I accidentally deleted it while posting, sorry. It added  now in the post. The error message is: The TensorFlow library was compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.

Comment: You'll likely need to [compile tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) yourself on that system. (The processor flags say it supports up to SSE2 but the package you're trying to install is pre-compiled to require SSE4.1.)

Comment: Hi @Freude, Your CPU is too old for running TensorFlow as it lacks the required Instruction set. Starting with TensorFlow 1.6, binaries use AVX instructions which may not run on older CPUs. For more details please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950186/tensorflow-library-was-compiled-to-use-sse4-1-instructions-but-these-arent-ava). Thank You.