# Python script requires Tensorflow which is not working

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am testing a python program named [`AptaNet`](https://github.com/nedaemami/AptaNet). The program is composed of 3 python scripts, running with python3.8:

(1) target_encoding.py,
(2) feature_extraction.py,
(3) predictor.py
Script 1) and 2) runs fine. Nothing to be done.

When it comes to Script (3) it is TensorFlow dependent and I get the following error:

```bash
bcramer@qsar:~/workdir-aptanet$ python3 predictor.py
> The TensorFlow library was compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
Aborted
```

If you want to help me and have TensorFlow v.2.9 maybe testing the scripts can lead to solve and/or identify the cause.
The program "repDNA" will have to be installed additionally:

```bash
pip install repDNA
```

Note: In the directory where you extract "aptanet" you get the a.m. 3 scripts and the Dataset.cvs. When testing "predictor.py" you will need Dataset.csv file to be present. Scripts 1 and 2 do not need to be tested.

Additional info:
Tensorflows installation:

```bash
sudo apt update sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv 
pip install --upgrade pip 
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install --user tensorflow-gpu
```

I am running the program in a old PC with 4GB RAM, Ubuntu20.04, Graphic card Nvidia GT-710 (1 GPU) which is new.

Comment: Your CPU is too old for the TensorFlow version you are trying to use. Tensorflow requires the specific SSE4.1 instructions, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4), but your CPU does not support those. 
Try a different version, and if this doesn't work, there is nothing you can do, other than to switch to a more modern CPU.

Comment: Already answered in this SO question [TensorFlow library was compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950186/tensorflow-library-was-compiled-to-use-sse4-1-instructions-but-these-arent-ava)

Comment: Related to the answer, is not saying much. What a is a too old PC in numbers. It was upgraded with an SSD and graphic card three months ago. When I try yo install TensorFlow v. 1.15 I get "No matching distribution found for TensorFlow==1.15.0" I really would appreciate help of somebody. Can some body that has Tensorflow installed, test the predict.py file as I mentioned? This would be great.Thank you.

Comment: No matching distribution found for TensorFlow==1.15.0" -> This can happen when your pip version is too old. Updating pip can fix the problem. 

Regarding a PC is too old. No-one said your PC is too old. Its your CPU that is too old. This is the main important point.  If you want a number of how many years too old? Check the release date of your CPU and compare it to the first CPU that supported SSE4.1 instructions. The difference is the amount of years your CPU is too old.